# ( django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'apps.accounts'. Check that 'mysite.apps.accounts.apps.AccountsConfig.name' is correct

Tags: python, django, django-templates, configure

This is how it is structured [image: The apps.py file is under apps which is under mysite]
The code inside **apps.py** of **accounts folder** file is

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = "apps.accounts"
```

The code inside Settings is

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mysite.apps.accounts',
]
```

I tried changing `'mysite.apps.accounts',` to `'mysite.apps.AccountsConfig',`
and changing `name = "apps.accounts"` to name = `"accounts"`
I am new to Django and was following [How to make a website with Python and Django - MODELS AND MIGRATIONS (E04)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCREG7J7JMg&t=977s) tutorial. Around [16:17](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCREG7J7JMg) is where my **error** comes up when I enter `python manage.py makemigrate` to the vscode terminal
The error is

> ImproperlyConfigured( django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
> Cannot import 'apps.accounts'. Check that
> 'mysite.apps.accounts.apps.AccountsConfig.name' is correct.
> Someone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was quite counterintuitive. You have to delete the

```
class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = "accounts"
```

from apps.py\accounts\apps\mysite. Then run `python manage.py makemigrations` and 2 new models '`UserPersona`' and '`UserProfile`' are created. the output in the terminal:

```
mysite\apps\accounts\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model UserPersona
    - Create model UserProfile
```

Comment: Sorry to bother, but didn't that modify or affect the functionality of your site as a whole?
I'm having the same issue as you, I believe

Answer (score 37):

The `name` in `apps.py` should be the same (value) that you put in `INSTALLED_APPS` (in `settings.py`). That's the correct one.

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
    name = "mysite.apps.accounts"
```

`settings.py` code:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mysite.apps.accounts',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The name in AppConfig should be same as the name provided in Installed Apps i.e., it should be "mysite.apps.accounts".