# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'apps.AppName' after upgrade to django 4

Tags: django

I have upgraded a django app which worked ok for years on django 3 to 4.1.4 and now it fails an error.
I anonymized the names.

In settings I have:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'foldername'

I've figured out that I needed to add Meta.app_label, can someone confirm?

So in foldername/apps.py I have now this:
class MyApp(AppConfig):
name = 'apps.MyApp'
class Meta:
app_label = 'apps.MyApp'

I'm not sure if the name needs to be apps.MyApp or just MyApp. I also have seen others posted to have foldername.apps.MyApp and have put the full name into INSTALLED_APP= (not just project/folder name). I wonder what's right.

Well, when I run: python manage.py, I get the stack trace:

....bla bla... strack trace ends with...
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'apps.MyApp'. Check that 'foldername.apps.MyApp.name' is correct.

Can anyone spot the problem?

I have spent so much time and don't know what to try. I've tried so much and rolled back again. Any feedback will make me happy at this point! :-)

David

Tried various combinations of: foldername.apps.MyApp (short, medium, long version) in name= in app_label, in moduleName and in INSTALLED_APPS.

Tried adding in models.ypy:

class BaseModel(models.Model):
class Meta:
abstract = True  # specify this model as an Abstract Model
app_label = 'apps.MyApp'

... and then let all models extend from it. I read about this in a forum as solution.

Comment: The name in **apps.py** should be the same as what is used in INSTALLED_APPS, so since you use `foldername` there, you should have `name = 'foldername'` in your **apps.py**.  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/72855390/10951070.

Comment: I set INSTALLED_APPS=MyApp and name also MyApp.
result is: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyApp'

It seems it can find it when I do INSTALLED_APPS=foldername.apps.MyApp but the fails:
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'MyApp'

Comment: In my project I have an app called `coding`, so that's the name of the folder. In INSTALLED_APPS I have a line `'coding'`, and in the **apps.py** within my coding folder I have `class CodingConfig(AppConfig): ... name = 'coding'`. My **apps.py** was automatically generated after I ran `python manage.py startapp coding`. I also don't see `app_label` being used in my **apps.py**, rather, if you need to give a label try looking [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.label).  If the naming is not the issue, then I'm out of ideas, sorry.