# ImportError: cannot import name 'UserProfile' from 'accounts.models' Django

Tags: django-models

I cannot import the UserProfile to admin.py,

Here is my models.py

```
from typing import Any
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.conf import settings
 
    class UserProfile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
        profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='user/profile', blank=True, null=True)
        cover_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='user/cover_photos', blank=True, null=True)
        address_line_1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null= True)
        address_line_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null= True)
        country = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
        state = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True) 
        pin_code = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, null=True) 
        latitude = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True) 
        longitude = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        
        def __str__(self): 
            return self.user.email
```

Here is my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User , UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin




class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name','last_name','role','is_active')
    ordering = ('-date_joined',)
    filter_horizontal = ()
    list_filter = ()
    fieldsets = ()
    
    
    
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
admin.site.register(UserProfile)
```

Error is : ImportError: cannot import name 'UserProfile' from 'accounts.models'

I need to add UserProfile to admin.py

Comment: what is your app name?

Comment: Food_Online_Web

Comment: I think Food_Online_Web is your project name . you can  try to import models.py with app name `from appname.models import User , UserProfile
`

Comment: Yes, you are right, app name is : 'accounts'

Comment: from django.apps import AppConfig


class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'accounts'

Comment: I still have this error. :(

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71529767/django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-cannot-import-apps-accounts-ch) might help you

Comment: Thanks, I read it. That was useful, but It did not work for me.

Comment: ok then can you provide your source code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this code by changes:

```
from accounts.models import User, UserProfile
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).